# Is it good/recommended to bypass ssl certificate from android app.if certificate changing every year on production

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, certificate

We have android native app and we are using retrofit 2.x for rest api call. I know how to bypass ssl certificate for call rest call. But I just want to know is it recommended to bypass ssl from android app.
Problem is that HTTPS certificate is changing on production every 1st day on each year.Apk is stable on production and we do not want to release apk just for HTTPs certificate.Can we keep this configurable and pick certificate from server at runtime instead of embedding it in apk.

Comment: No, its generally not a good practice. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). It sounds like you should pin the issuing CA certificate, and not the end-entity/server certificate.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it good/recommended to bypass ssl certificate

No. It is radically insecure. Do not do this.

> from android app.if certificate changing every month on production

Irrelevant. It is still insecure.

The server certificate should be signed by a recognized CA that your application trusts. That won't change every month, more like every 20 years.